# How to import Dictionary text file and check for word matches?

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I generate a random string of 500 characters and want to check for words.

```
bliduuwfhbgphwhsyzjnlfyizbjfeeepsbpgplpbhaegyepqcjhhotovnzdtlracxrwggbcmjiglasjvmscvxwazmutqiwppzcjhijjbguxfnduuphhsoffaqwtmhmensqmyicnciaoczumjzyaaowbtwjqlpxuuqknxqvmnueknqcbvkkmildyvosczlbnlgumohosemnfkmndtiubfkminlriytmbtrzhwqmovrivxxojbpirqahatmydqgulammsnfgcvgfncqkpxhgikulsjynjrjypxwvlkvwvigvjvuydbjfizmbfbtjprxkmiqpfuyebllzezbxozkiidpplvqkqlgdlvjbfeticedwomxgawuphocisaejeonqehoipzsjgbfdatbzykkurrwwtajeajeornrhyoqadljfjyizzfluetynlrpoqojxxqmmbuaktjqghqmusjfvxkkyoewgyckpbmismwyfebaucsfueuwgio
```

I import a [Dictionary Words txt file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dolph/dictionary/master/popular.txt) and check the `string` to see if it contains each word. If a match is found, it's added to a list.

---

I read using `Dictionary<>` is faster than `Array` for a words list.

When I use that method, I can see the cpu working the foreach loop in the debugger, and my loop counter goes up, about 10,000+ times in 10 seconds, but the loop continues on forever and does not return any results.

When I use `Array` for Dictionary, the program works, but slower at around 500 times in 10 seconds.

---

**Not Working**

Using `Dictionary<>`

```
// Random Message
public string message = Random(500);

// Dictionary Words Reference
public Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// Matches Found
public static List<string> matches = new List<string>();


public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Import Dictionary File
    dictionary = File
                    .ReadLines(@"C:\dictionary.txt")
                    .Select((v, i) => new { Index = i, Value = v })
                    .GroupBy(p => p.Index / 2)
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.First().Value, g => g.Last().Value);


    // If Message Contains word, add to Matches List
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dictionary)
    {
        if (message.Contains(entry.Value))
        {
            matches.Add(entry.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Working**

Using `Array`

```
// Random Message
public string message = Random(500);

// Dictionary Words Reference
public string[] dictionary = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\dictionary.txt");

// Matches Found
public List<string> matches = new List<string>();


public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // If Message Contains word, add to Matches List
    foreach (var entry in dictionary)
    {
        if (message.Contains(entry))
        {
            matches.Add(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt if you want `Dictionary<string, string>` as a *dictionary* ;) `HashSet<string>` will be enough:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string source = "bliduuwfhbgphwhsyzjnlfyizbj";

  HashSet<string> allWords = new HashSet<string>(File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\dictionary.txt")
    .Select(line => line.Trim())
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  int shortestWord = allWords.Min(word => word.Length);
  int longestWord = allWords.Max(word => word.Length);

  // If you want duplicates, change HashSet<string> to List<string>
  HashSet<string> wordsFound = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  for (int length = shortestWord; length <= longestWord; ++length) {
    for (int position = 0; position <= source.Length - length; ++position) {
      string extract = source.Substring(position, length);

      if (allWords.Contains(extract))
        wordsFound.Add(extract); 
    }
  }
```

Test: for

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dolph/dictionary/master/popular.txt

dictionary donwloaded as `C:\dictionary.txt` file

```
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", wordsFound.OrderBy(x => x)));
```

we have output

```
  id, li, lid
```

Comment: About to try this, got code in place, but I'm getting an error for 'words' does not exist for words.Min and words.Max.

Comment: @Matt McManis: Please ensure you've added `using System.Linq;` since `Min` and `Max` are extension methods

Comment: using System.Linq; is there, but what is 'words', is it supposed to be allWords? It says it's not found.

Comment: @Matt McManis: I'm sorry for typo, it should be `allWords` in both cases

Comment: I'm getting `Value cannot be null.` on if `(allWords.Contains(extract))`. Should there be some kind of null check in case there are no words found? Why would it be getting null error?

Comment: @Matt McManis: I've run the code and it does work; let's debug your code: put a breakpoint on `if (allWords.Contains(extract))`, and check what instance is `null`: `extract`,  `allWords`? Check `allWords` as well: does it look OK? I've expected file being organized as one word in a line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160627/discussion-between-matt-mcmanis-and-dmitry-bychenko).

Comment: It looks like `allWords` is null. I updated my dictionary link, The dictionary.txt is this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dolph/dictionary/master/popular.txt.

Comment: Well, as you can see I create the `allWords`: `HashSet<string> allWords = new HashSet<string>(...);` so, please put a break point on this line, ensure that `allWords` has been created, and if it's been, step line after line to find out where it has been assigned to `null`; file format is OK (`25322` items).

Comment: I had conflicting old code overriding the `allWords`. It appears to be working now, thanks. However it's disabled my UI from displaying in real time while it's running, unlike when I was using Array. But that's another issue with threading I think.

Comment: If you run the code in a separated thread, please check `InvokeRequired` and call `Invoke` when required when printing out the outcome with UI

Comment: I'm going to mark this as solved, I'm going to make another question about threading this if you want to answer it, I'll post link. I'm using a thread and using dispatcher on UI, but don't know if it's done properly.

Comment: @Matt McManis: The most expesive operation in the code - loading dictionary:`HashSet<string> allWords = new HashSet<string>(...);` when you have the file loaded all the rest code will cost you milliseconds (about 10ms at my workstation for your initial long string). Do you really want threading?

Comment: On my larger project experiment I'm using a `while loop` that runs a string against a dictionary over and over thousands of times. My UI would hang until I threaded it. When I use your code out of Debug mode it seems to be displaying the UI now.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Dictionary in this scenario doesn't make much sense. A Dictionary is, essentially, a list of variables that stores both the variable name and the variable value.

I could have the following:

```
int age = 21;
int money = 21343;
int distance = 10;
int year = 2017;
```

And convert it to a Dictionary instead, using the following:

```
Dictionary<string, int> numbers = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    { "age", 21 },
    { "money", 21343},
    { "distance", 10 },
    { "year", 2017 }
};
```

And then I can access a value in the dictionary using its key (the first value). So, for example, if I want to know what "age" is, I would use:

```
Console.Log(numbers["age"]);
```

This is only a single example of the power of dictionaries - there is a LOT more that they can do, and they can make your life a lot easier. In this scenario, however, they aren't going to do what you're expecting them to do. I would suggest just using the Array, or a List.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the dictionary,
you are basically using the dictionary as a list, so it only added some overhead to the program. not helping in any way.

It would have been useful if you had something you want to query against the dictionary not the other way around.

Also, in any case, what you want is a HashSet, not a dictionary since your key in the dictionary is not the word you are querying against but an irrelevant int.

you can read more about dictionary and HashSet here:

**dictionary:** https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary 
**hashset:** https://www.dotnetperls.com/hashset